# Sort array from Axios React

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I sort array I cant use map.

```
var arrQuestByDate = new Array();
action.payload.data.forEach(function(item){
  if(typeof(arrQuestByDate[item.date])==='undefined'){
    arrQuestByDate[item.date]= new Array();  
  }
  arrQuestByDate[item.date].push(item);
  console.log(arrQuestByDate[item.date].length) //this output good value
})
console.log(arrQuestByDate.length) //this output 0
```

I dont know why my array length is 0

Comment: The square bracket syntax is for objects, not arrays.

Comment: you should post your entire code...

Comment: What is that `arrQuestByDate[item.date]` ?

Comment: Looking at your code, `arrQuestByDate` should be object. Please share input and expected output.

Comment: This is my new array arrQuestByDate[date of quest] then i push to this item. I wnat to group elements by date

Comment: There is nothing related to Axios nor to React in this code, your issue may lie in code you did not shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy) function from lodash.
If you don't want to use external library, this code shoudl work

```
var quotestByDate = action.payload.data
    .reduce( function(acc, quote) {     
        if (!acc[quote.date]) {
            acc[quote.date] = [];
        }
        acc[quote.date].push(quote);
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(Object.keys(quotestByDate).length);
```